# How not stack columns when print a form with BootStrap 3.0 on IE 9.0?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to print a form and keep the two columns presentation.

In FireFox, it's ok. But in IE 9, all the columns are stack in one raw for each.

How can i fix that?

I've do this form :

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="Area/MyForm" method="post" id="FormID">
<div class="block_1 border">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nocmpt" class="col-lg-4 control-label ">N° d'ordre(*) :</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input id="nordre" name="nordre" class="form-control" type="text" readonly="readonly" onfocus="this.blur()" value="1234679" />
                </div>
              </div>
         </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="mtremi" class="col-lg-4 control-label  ">Montant Remise :</label>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input id="mtremi" name="mtremi" class="form-control" type="text" title="Ex: 15000" value="100,00" tabindex="2" />
                </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="" />
    <span class="noprint">(*)=champs non modifiables</span>
</div>
</form>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.

Here, the code running :
http://jsfiddle.net/rnPeJ/

Visual print on IE 9 (Wrong) :
    [image]
Visual print on FF (Ok) :
    [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my problem by add "col-xs-6" like :

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
```

Comment: I wasn't dealing with printing, but with an IE alignment issue.  By specifying all the column values for all sizes it resolved my issue.